# Referência de objeto não definida, oque poderia ser?

Tags: c#, winforms

"*Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.*"

```
Button[,] botoes = new Button[(int)numericUpDownLinhas.Value, (int)numericUpDownColunas.Value];
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)numericUpDownLinhas.Value; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < (int)numericUpDownColunas.Value; j++)
        {
            botoes[i, j].BackColor = button1.BackColor;
            botoes[i, j].Size = new Size((int)numericUpDownX.Value, (int)numericUpDownY.Value);
            botoes[i, j].Location = new Point(18 + j * ((int)numericUpDownX.Value + 4), 35 + i * ((int)numericUpDownY.Value + 4));
            this.Controls.Add(botoes[i, j]);
        }
    }
```

Da erro nessas 3 linhas:

```
botoes[i, j].BackColor = button1.BackColor;
botoes[i, j].Size = new Size((int)numericUpDownX.Value, (int)numericUpDownY.Value);
botoes[i, j].Location = new Point(18 + j * ((int)numericUpDownX.Value + 4), 35 + i * ((int)numericUpDownY.Value + 4));
```

Alguém saberia dizer o por que?

Comment: O erro só pode acontecer em uma linha, qual delas é? Coloque o erro de forma mais completa. É uma das três variáveis usadas que não está disponível nesse escopo.

Comment: oque poderia ser? só pede ser Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto. rsrs você esta tentando acesse o value de uma variavél que esta null.

Comment: Eu disse que da erro nas três linhas pois primeiro aponta erro na primeira, se eu comentar ele, aponta na segunda, etc...

Comment: Mas como assim o valor da variável ta null se no começo do código eu defini botoes?

Comment: Nullpointer é relativamente fácil de encontrar, quando você estiver debugando e der essa exceção, basta ir na linha do erro e colocar o mouse em cima dos objetos e procurar qual deles esta nulo e precisa ser instanciado.

Comment: Eu resolvi já, eu achei que quando a gente fazia o array, já tava tudo definido, mas depois tem que ir definindo de um em um botoes[i, j] = new Button();

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi! Antes das três linhas mencionadas eu coloquei o seguinte:
`botoes[i, j] = new Button();`